# Declaring a variable for use between methods

Tags: java, variables, csv, formatter

I need to look up variables from a csv file, then print that variable to another file using a formatter.

This formatter will essentially be a template to print a number of different files using different data characteristics contained in the csv file.

Sort of like printing player statistics for a number of different baseball players using the same formatted file.

I've declared the variables (SOI, SGI, SWI) within the class and set up the formatter:

```
public class JavaPractice {

static double SOI;
static double SGI;
static double SWI;

private Formatter ei;

public void eorFile(){
    try{
        ei = new Formatter("M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\JAVA for NEMS\\JavaPractice\\eorinput.ind");

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Then I have another method to read the variables from the csv file:

```
public void eorDB(){
    String csvFile = "M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\JAVA for NEMS\\EORModule\\NEMSEORDBEX1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String [] reservoir = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            String SOI = reservoir[1];
            String SGI = reservoir[2];
            String SWI = reservoir[3];
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Then I have tried to print the variables using the formatter, but the variables don't seem to be picked up from the eorDB method

public void addData(){

```
    ei.format("%d%d%d%n", SOI, SGI, SWI);

    }

public void closeFile(){
    ei.close();
}
```

However, the SOI, SGI, and SWI variables do not seem to be shared properly between the methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Try calling _addData()_ inside your loop.  Your current code continually overwrites your variables, so they will only reflect the correct value for the **last line you process**.

Comment: You're redeclaring your variables inside the loop... This is bad.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling *addData()* from within your loop (so you don't overwrite the variables each iteration).

**Also**, you're accidentally **declaring** new, local variables with the same name (by including the word **String** in front of them).

If you want to use the class variables, **do not declare new variables**!

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String [] reservoir = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
     SOI = reservoir[1]; // do NOT declare a new string here!
     SGI = reservoir[2];
     SWI = reservoir[3];
     addData();          // invoke addData() with current values
 }
```

---

**However...** it's quickly obvious that there's no need for class variables here (you could just use local variables):

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String [] s = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
     String o = s[1];
     String g = s[2];
     String w = s[3];
     ei.format("%d%d%d%n", o, g, w);
 }
```